# Configuring JNDI Spring boot application

Tags: maven, spring-boot, datasource, jndi

I am using a Spring boot application where the default configuration of datasouce is done using the following properties in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=${datasource.driver.className}
spring.datasource.url=${datasource.url}
spring.datasource.username=${datasource.username}
spring.datasource.password=${datasource.password}
```

The thing is that this works well when i run the spring boot run command through local maven, however i need to configure the things in such a way that when i try to to a maven build to create a war the configuration puts a JNDI name as:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/
```

Can i make it configurable through maven or any other way that when we deploy it through Spring boot it picks above 4 properties and when we create a war it picks only the JNDI property.

-Vaibhav

Comment: having 2 seperate configuration files certainly helps but what if we want the JNDI lookup to be default and the local configuration to unset this using other properties file. So that when we do a build without explicit mention of spring profile it builds with JNDI lookup and with an explicit mention does the datasource build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Spring profiles for that. For example, create a file called `application-local.properties` and add the first four properties to it:

```
# application-local.properties
spring.datasource.driverClassName=${datasource.driver.className}
spring.datasource.url=${datasource.url}
spring.datasource.username=${datasource.username}
spring.datasource.password=${datasource.password}
```

Then create another file names `application-jndi.properties`:

```
# application-jndi.properties
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/
```

Now all you have to do is to add the VM argument `-Dspring.profiles.active=local` (or add the `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local` environment variable) to the command when you run it locally, and `-Dspring.profiles.active=jndi` when you need to run it with JNDI.

It isn't exactly automatic depending on the Maven packaging type, but configuring the Spring profile per environment isn't difficult either. You could also set one of the both configuration properties as default (in `application.properties`) so you don't have to configure the profile as much.

Comment: "You could also set one of the both configuration properties as default (in application.properties) so you don't have to configure the profile as much." can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: If you set the `spring.datasource.jndi-name` property in the `application.properties` and you unset it in the `application-local.properties`, then you don't need the `application-jndi.properties` because that's the default now if you run without profile.

Comment: Yes i tried to do that but could not figure out a way to unset the property, actually it considers application.properties as parent, setting to null again threw an exception.

Comment: Does it not work if you leave it empty? `spring.datasource.jndi-name=` (and then a newline)

Comment: nope it says Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name ''"